# Relationship field orderby/sort listing lowercase after caps?

Tags: relationships, orderby, sort

I'm currently running EE 2.9.2 on a site. I have a relationship field that takes all selected entries and sorts them by a custom channel field for the display title.

I've used this specific call:

`{relationship orderby="custom_field" sort="asc"}`

Only problem is that this field has several instances where it begins with a lowercase letter, due to a company's name being written that way (and thus unable to be capitalized). The returned values will place them outside of all of the entries beginning with capital letters, regardless of the letter they start with.

Example:

> Leonardo
>
> Michelangelo
>
> donatello
>
> raphael

Does anyone know of any way to override this specific rule?

Mucho thanks in advance.